# Is pullback of a quasi-coherent sheaf, quasi-coherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm very new to this whole sheaf business and very confused, so forgive me if the question is dumb (or not, I have no idea really).

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on $Y$. For simplicity say $Y$ is an affine variety. Suppose we have a map $f:X\to Y$ (suppose $X$ is also an affine variety), I'm wondering if the inverse image (pullback) sheaf $f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ is quasi-coherent? And if so what is the relation between their corresponding modules?

---

Let me tell you about my own attempt:

I know that any quasi-coherent sheaf is isomorphic to $\tilde{M}=M\otimes_{k[Y]}\mathscr{O}_Y$ where $M$ is a $k[Y]$-module. The map $f$ also induces a map $f^*: k[Y]\to k[X]$, meaning $k[X]$ is a $k[Y]$-algebra. By extension of scalars we find a $k[X]$-$k[Y]$ bimodule $M\otimes_{k[Y]}k[X]$. Then
$$\tilde{M} = M\otimes_{k[Y]}\mathscr{O}_Y =(M\otimes_{k[Y]}k[X])\otimes_{k[X]}\mathscr{O}_Y$$
The only thing stopping the above sheaf to be sheaf on $X$ is $\mathscr{O}_Y$ not being $\mathscr{O}_X$. So I thought maybe we have (very naively)
$$
f^{-1}\tilde{M} = (M\otimes_{k[Y]}k[X])\otimes_{k[X]}\mathscr{O}_X
$$
I searched a little bit and seems like this is actually true. So I thought of proving it. It is enough we show it for a basis of topology of $X$, say $D(g)=\{x\in X|g(x)\neq 0\}$ for $g\in k[X]$. Then by definition
$$
\Gamma(D(g), f^{-1}\tilde{M})=\varinjlim_{V\supset f(D(g))} \Gamma(V, \tilde{M})=M\otimes_{k[Y]}
\varinjlim_{V\supset f(D(g))} \Gamma(V, \mathscr{O}_Y)
$$
which is $(M\otimes_{k[Y]}k[X])\otimes_{k[X]} \Gamma(D(g), f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_Y)$. This means $$f^{-1}\tilde{M} = (M\otimes_{k[Y]}k[X])\otimes_{k[X]} f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_Y$$
But do we have $f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_Y=\mathscr{O}_X$? I don't so (I mean for any $f$ this is true? really?)! But if it is, how do we prove it? Also in the above argument is there any flaws?

Comment: $f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ is not even a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules. You probably want $f^*\mathscr{F}$. In the latter case, yes, pullback $f^*$ of (quasi-)coherent is (quasi-)coherent and $f^*(\mathcal{O}_Y)=\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: Oh you're right I forgot about putting the sheafification. Other than sheafification is there any other difference between $f^{-1}$ and $f^*$?

Comment: I don't think any sheafification is missing (at least not from the stuff from before your attempt; the attempt I haven't read). Hartshorne defines $f^*\mathscr{F}$ as $f^{-1}\mathscr{F}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal{O}_X$ where the $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ structure on $\mathcal{O}_X$ comes from the natural map of sheaves of rings $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: To be clear, in my first comment, I'm NOT saying that $f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ isn't a sheaf. It is a sheaf. I'm saying it's not a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules, i.e. you can't multiply sections of $f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ by functions on $X$.

Comment: I looked up the definition of $f^*$ and my head is now both more clear and more confused. My confusion is because apparently if we have $\tilde{M}=M\otimes_{k[Y]}\mathscr{O}_Y$, under $f^*$ it goes to $f^*\tilde{M}=(M\otimes_{k[Y]}k[X])\otimes_{k[X]}\mathscr{O}_X$. So it doesn't matter what $f$ is? The result is the same always? Where did the extra information go?

Comment: If $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ is an $A$-algebra, and $M$ is an $A$-module, then the $B$-module isomorphism type of $M\otimes_{A}B$ depends upon $\phi$ even though that doesn't appear in the notation.